# How to find the number of common tokens between each individual text among many texts without a double loop?

Tags: python, token

I have a large number of small tokenized texts and I want to find the number of common tokens between all of these texts in the form of an upper triangular matrix M (the matrix could also be symmetric). If M[i,j]=1, it means that i and j have 1 token in common.

I can't find another way of doing it than with a double loop, which is not time efficient. Is there any?

In the below code, `subjects` is a list of the lists of tokens in each text.

```py
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

n = len(subjects)
M = lil_matrix((n, n))

i = 0
for subj_1 in subjects:
    j = 0
    for subj_2 in subjects[i+1:]:
        inter_len = len(list(set(subj_1).intersection(subj_2)))
        if inter_len>0:
            M[i,j+i+1] = inter_len
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: About how many different tokens are there?

Comment: The number varies across the different texts, about 15 per text. In total I have about 50,000 different tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I will present you with three options. Your base algorithm can be improved in a number of ways. Instead of appending to a sparse matrix, just use a preallocated array, even if you are not filling it entirely. In addition to that, you can convert the subjects to sets only once at the beginning to avoid repeating work. So you get:

```
import numpy as np

def count_common_tokens(subjects):
    n = len(subjects)
    counts = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int32)
    subjects_sets = [set(subject) for subject in subjects]
    for i1, subj_1 in enumerate(subjects_sets):
        for i2 in range(i1 + 1, n):
            subj_2 = subjects_sets[i2]
            counts[i1, i2] = len(subj_1.intersection(subj_2))
    return counts
```

The problem is of quadratic complexity by nature. But we can try to vectorize it with NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

def count_common_tokens_vec(subjects):
    n = len(subjects)
    # Concatenate all subjects
    all_subjects = np.concatenate(subjects)
    # Make subject ids from subject lengths
    lens = [len(subject) for subject in subjects]
    subject_ids = np.repeat(np.arange(n), lens)
    # Find unique token ids
    all_tokens, token_ids = np.unique(all_subjects, return_inverse=True)
    # Make array where each row represents the token presents in each subject
    subject_token = np.zeros((n, len(all_tokens)), dtype=np.int32)
    np.add.at(subject_token, (subject_ids, token_ids), 1)
    subject_token = subject_token.astype(bool)
    # Logical and with itself to find number of common tokens
    counts = np.count_nonzero(subject_token[:, np.newaxis] & subject_token[np.newaxis, :], axis=-1)
    return counts
```

This gives you the full matrix of counts (instead of just the upper triangle), but it may take a lot of memory, in the order of `O(num_subjects x num_subjecs x num_tokens)`, so it will probably not work well for a big problem. We can however try to speed things up with Numba, if you really need it. It forces you to do things a little differently, working with arrays of numbers instead of sets of strings (maybe there is a better way to do the first part here), but we can get the result we want with it too.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def count_common_tokens_nb(subjects):
    n = len(subjects)
    # Output array
    counts = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.int32)
    # Concatenate all subjects
    all_subjects = np.concatenate(subjects)
    # Find token ids for concatenated subjects
    _, token_ids = np.unique(all_subjects, return_inverse=True)
    # Split token ids and remove duplicates
    lens = [len(subject) for subject in subjects]
    subjects_sets = [np.unique(s) for s in np.split(token_ids, np.cumsum(lens)[:-1])]
    # Do the counting
    _count_common_tokens_nb_inner(counts, subjects_sets)
    return counts

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def _count_common_tokens_nb_inner(counts, subjects_sets):
    n = len(subjects_sets)
    for i1 in nb.prange(n):
        subj_1 = subjects_sets[i1]
        for i2 in nb.prange(i1 + 1, n):
            subj_2 = subjects_sets[i2]
            c = 0
            for t1 in subj_1:
                for t2 in subj_2:
                    c += int(t1 == t2)
            counts[i1, i2] = c
    return counts
```

Here is a quick test and a small performance comparison.

```
import random
import string
import numpy as np

NUM_SUBJECTS = 1000
MAX_TOKENS_SUBJECT = 20
NUM_TOKENS = 5000
MAX_LEN_TOKEN = 10

# Make random input
random.seed(0)
letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
tokens = np.array(list(set(''.join(random.choices(letters, k=random.randint(1, MAX_LEN_TOKEN)))
                           for _ in range(NUM_TOKENS))))
subjects = [np.array(random.choices(tokens, k=random.randint(1, MAX_TOKENS_SUBJECT)))
            for _ in range(NUM_SUBJECTS)]
# Do counts
res1 = count_common_tokens(subjects)
res2 = count_common_tokens_vec(subjects)
res3 = count_common_tokens_nb(subjects)
# Check results
print(np.all(np.triu(res1, 1) == np.triu(res2, 1)))
# True
print(np.all(np.triu(res1, 1) == np.triu(res3, 1)))
# True

# Test performance
%timeit count_common_tokens(subjects)
# 196 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit count_common_tokens_vec(subjects)
# 5.09 s ± 30.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit count_common_tokens_nb(subjects)
# 65.2 ms ± 886 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So the vectorized solution did not work well, but with Numba you do get a significant speedup.